# Transfer file from amazon s3 account to another

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am writing an app and we need to transfer files between different s3 accounts, we don't want to save file locally before uploading to the destination s3 account.
So we get the source file stream using this:

```
public Stream GetFileStream(string path)
{
    var pathPieces = path.Split('/');
    string bucket = pathPieces[0];
    string fileName = pathPieces[pathPieces.Length - 1];

    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
    request.BucketName = bucket;
    request.Key = fileName;

    GetObjectResponse response = Client.GetObject(request);

    return response.ResponseStream;
}
```

And after that we use this stream to upload on the destination:

```
    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(Client);
    transferUtility.S3Client.PutBucket(new PutBucketRequest() { UseClientRegion = true }.WithBucketName(bucket));
    TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
    .WithBucketName(bucket)
    .WithKey(key)
    .WithPartSize(1024)
    .WithTimeout(100 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    .WithAutoCloseStream(true)
    .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicReadWrite)
    .WithInputStream(fileStream) as TransferUtilityUploadRequest;

    transferUtility.Upload(request);
```

But on the last line "Upload" function call i always get this error:
**This stream does not support seek operations.**

Is there a different way to do what I am trying to do? because it seams not the correct way

Comment: In a way, while streaming, you are anyway downloading entire file and uploading back the same file, you are not saving any bandwidth here, instead let it save as local file and then upload it. Unnecessary you want to block buffers in memory or block network operations, this is not a good practice.

Comment: My Idea is to get some bytes [buffersize] and transfer them, then get others and transfer them, like this if 100 GB of files are transferring in the same time, my hard disk will not get full. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: For such huge files, it will fail anyway, for 100GB file transfer there will be many network failures, and for upload, S3 needs file length first so that it can divide files in multiple parts and upload simultaneously. So without downloading entire file first, transfer utility will not work.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question, and am posting the approach I used to solve it.  Borrowed some some code from Jon Skeet.  It worked for me, but I know it's a bit clunky and can probably be improved.

```
string filename = "nameoffiletocopy"

using (Stream stream = GetS3Stream(filename))
{
    AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config 
        {CommunicationProtocol = Protocol.HTTP};
    AmazonS3 client = 
        AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(
            "destinationaccesskey",
            "destinationsecretacceskey", 
            config);
    string destinationBucketName = "destinationbucketname";

    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = destinationBucketName,
        InputStream = stream,
        Key = filename,
        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
    };

    PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);     
}

private static Stream GetS3Stream(string filename)
{
    AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config 
        {CommunicationProtocol = Protocol.HTTP};
    AmazonS3 client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(
        "sourceaccesskey",
        "sourcesecretacceskey", 
        config);
    string sourceBucketName = "sourcebucketname";

    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest 
        {
            BucketName = sourceBucketName, 
            Key = filename
        };

    using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
    {
        byte[] binaryData = 
        ReadFully(response.ResponseStream, -1);
        //ReadyFully from Jon Skeet's blog
        return new MemoryStream(binaryData);
    }
}
```

ReadFully method explained fully by [Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think there is a way to transfer between accounts. The only protocol I know that can do this is [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol). You can make a request to AWS to do this in the future, would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has a Copy Object Request

```
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();

CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest {
      SourceBucket = "fromBucket",
      SourceKey = "fromFile",
      DestinationBucket = "toBucket",
      DestinationKey = "toFilename",
      CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl
 };

 CopyObjectResponse response = client.CopyObject(request);
```

Comment: but this works inside the same S3 account not 2 different accounts.